# MySQL - Select specific rows and only then randomize them

Tags: mysql

When I write `'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50'` mysql has to randomize the entire table then only fetch 50.
What I want to do (in mysql, preferably not in php) is to fetch 50 rows THEN randomize them.

Is there a way to do this in Mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM    (
            SELECT * 
            FROM table 
            LIMIT 50
        ) sub
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: doesn't work. it says: "every derived table has to have its own alias"

Comment: oh I just needed to provide it an alias after the closing brace.